# How to show only 5 elements of each foreign ID elements in ORM query?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-queryset

| id | comment | answer_id | question_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 4 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 5 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 6 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 7 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 11 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 12 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 13 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 14 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 15 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 16 | some comment | 2 | 1 |
| 17 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 18 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 19 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 20 | some comment | 42 | 1 |
| 21 | some comment | 42 | 1 |

Above is the table of name `Comment` which contains comments of answers and questions.
Note:  I have two more tables that is `Answer` and `Question` which contains data of question and answer.

I want to get the records of only first 5 of each answer_id i.e.,(`2` and `42`) of that particular question_id i.e., (`1`).

Following is the query I have tried,

```
answer = Answer.objects.filter(question=question_id)
answer_comment = Comment.objects.filter(answer_id__in=answer.values('id'))
```

but the above query gives all the data of specific question.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: how do you define *first*? Based on what order?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Using SQL server (Mysql) database.

 top 5 with default order.

Answer (score 2):

Given you said "default order", I'm going to assume you want "first 5 comments" to mean "the 5 comments with the lowest id (primary key) values" for each answer of a given question (with id `question_id` in this example). Also assuming "5 or fewer" (there might only be 3 comments for one answer)

To achieve this, I would use **window functions** ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions), [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)) like so:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber


n_comments_per_answer = 5

comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    answer__question_id=question_id
).annotate(
    row_number=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(),
        # question_id isn't actually required in the partition_by since
        # you only require answers of one question but will be if you
        # remove this filter
        partition_by=[F('question_id'), F('answer_id')],
        order_by=answer_id
    )
).filter(
    row_number__lte=n_comments_per_answer
)
```

another simpler solution if you don't mind not having all comments in a single queryset but rather as an iterable is to just pull every answer and their related comments for a question and do the work in python:

```py
answers = Answer.objects.prefetch_related('comment_set').filter(question_id=question_id)
# using a list but it could be a generator expression too
comments = [
    comment
    for answer in answers
    for comment in list(answer.comment_set.all())[:5]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's raising `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.`

Comment: I'm guessing you're using an older Django version? I just saw this in the documentation:
>Changed in Django 4.2:
>Support for filtering against window functions was added.